# Install Python 2.7.6 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Hi i am trying to install python2.7.6 on my 16.04 cloud image. Its giving the following on - `apt install python=2.7.6`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python
```

Comment: There is no package `python` There is a package called `python2.7` so maybe that is what you are looking for?

Comment: https://github.com/micktwomey/docker-python2.7/blob/master/Dockerfile go through this docker file and check you are using right commands.

Comment: it seems that the sources file was being modified vi /etc/apt/sources.list is empty

Comment: I'll give you a link of an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/378565) to a very similar question.
Tell me if it works!

Answer (score 1):

> > Install Python 2.7.6:

```
$ wget  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz  
$ tar xvfz Python-2.7.6.tgz
$ cd Python-2.7.6/
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

INFO SOURCE: [SOURCE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050084/install-python-2-7-6-in-ubuntu-16-04)